# How i do i change this code so it can deal with functions

Tags: python, function

The function below takes 3 parameters (f, a, and b). Here f is a function and a and b are lower and
upper bounds respectively, and f is the function to be summed over. #to calculate the sum of f from a to b

```
def sum(f, a, b):
 total = 0
 for i in range(a, b+1):
 total += f(i)
 return total
```

Question 1. Type in the above code and calculate the sum of integers from 1 to 10, and 1 to 100 and
1 to 1000

Comment: Initialize `total` to `1` and do `total *= f(i)` instead of the `+=` operator?

Answer (score 1):

Similar idea, but use `*=` instead of `+=`

```
def product(f, a, b):
    total = 1
    for i in range(a, b+1):
        total *= f(i)
    return total
```

For example

```
def foo(x):
    return x

>>> product(foo, 1, 5)
120
```

Comment: @CoryKramer, upvoited you, I used some of you code for my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just as adding 0 does nothing, multiplying by 1 does nothing.  Therefore, just use that as the start:

```
def product(f, a, b):
    total = 1
    for i in range(a, b+1):
        total *= f(i)
    return total
```

Comment: then would you print product and then pass the three values or?

Comment: @TurtleDave: It would have the same usage as `sum()`.

Comment: @TurtleDave: It should be `print product(f, 1, 5)`.  I changed the name.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a functional style and you will come to success:

```
def product(f, a, b):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [f(n) for n in range(a, b+1)])
```

---

Run it going with function eg `spam`:

```
def spam(x):
    return x

print(product(spam, 1, 3))

>>>6
```

**Edited:**

W/o `f` param it will looks:

```
def product(a, b):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [n for n in range(a, b+1)])
print(product(1, 5))
```

Comment: how would i print the answer?

Comment: Okay i dont understand the concept of the def spam part? Once you define the product do you def spam after?

Comment: because `f(n)` is function here, which you pass to you methods `sum` or `product` like you pass `int` a and b. So you have to define function to pass it

Comment: but I don't know what you pass function for. To count product you will be fine w/o `f`: `def product(a, b):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [n for n in range(a, b+1)])`

Comment: No i dont understand how to run this in python, when i try defining then printing it is just saying syntax error

Comment: You tried this? `def product(a, b): return reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [n for n in range(a, b+1)])`

Comment: Yeah, what do i do after i have put that in python?

Comment: eg put also `print(product(1,5))`

Comment: Yeah i have done this, still get syntax i just think python hates me XD

Comment: I edited answer. It tested, It works. Hope it will help

Comment: Sorry, @TurtleDave, you have to read something before start with Python. Indentation in Python is very important. You hit syntax errors because you don't know syntax of Python.  youtube.com/watch?v=Cd-k6QQMa18

Comment: Thanks so much :)! I got it working.  How would i change the code so that function became factorial?  () means f(1)*f(2)*f(3)??

Comment: it's already factorial. product of list of values between `a` and `b` eg between 1 and 5 [1,2,3,4,5] = 120

Comment: So if i used this as my code def product(f, a, b):
    total = 1
    for i in range(a, b+1):
        total *= f(i)
    return total.       How would i change this to calculate the sum??